# Getting wrong return values when using reflection to call a static method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have 2 types called `Effect` and `EffectMethods` which is the static class I am calling the method of:

```
public class EffectMethods
{
    public static EffectResult Blend (Effect effect)
    {
        bool success = true;
        return new EffectResult ( effect.Type, success );
    }
}
```

I find the right method using:

```
Type.GetMethods ( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static );
```

and filter out the right one.

But when I call it:

```
( EffectResult ) method.Invoke ( null, new object [ ] { this } );
public class Effect
{
    public EffectResult Apply()
    {
        var methods = Type.GetMethods ( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static );
        var method = methods.First ( ... );

        // This result value is now different (success = false)
        return ( EffectResult ) method.Invoke ( null, new object [ ] { this } );
    }
}
```

I am getting the wrong result. Here `this` is the current instance of `Effect` because it's the type that includes the reflection call.

Basically one of the values I calculate is a flag that returns whether the operation is successful. But this value is set to true in code, but after the method returns via reflection the result is different.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there something I am missing? I can clearly see the value to be true inside the method but on the call site, it shows up differently.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the Blend() method?

Comment: Maybe add some more complete code. I still don't see how you get a `this` inside a static method.

Comment: I added the code for the Blend, which is how it is now, as I am debugging it like this. Type.GetMethods and method.Invoke, those are inside the Effect instance class which calls the Blend method via reflection.

Comment: Your variable success is scoped to the static method, not declared as a static member on your EffectMethods class, correct? Are you using any lambda expressions inside your static method?

Comment: @Joel, that's correct and no lambda. It's literally setting some values like success and creating an instance of EffectResult.

Comment: I think you need to post more code, I tried to recreate below using the types you have defined and filling in the others (wasn't sure if Type was a system type or an enum) and got it to work...

Comment: Ok added some more code. I don't know what else could do this. I will see if I can find more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why it should return "bad value". You didn't provide complete code, so I can only give you my two guesses.

1. In the constructor of `EffectResult`, you forgot to set the `success` parameter to a property, or the property implementation is wrong.
2. The `Type` you use to get the methods from is other than `EffectMethods` or you have duplicate assemblies with different implementations in your AppDomain. Check the loaded Modules.

Comment: You were right with #1, just checked and it was true. Can't believe I missed this. Thanks alot for helping me out.

Comment: It happens :-) even the smallest of mistakes bite us from time to time.

Comment: Yeah I know, but hate it when it happens to me :O

Answer (score 1):

Can you post more code?  I'm guessing on some of the definitions based on the code you're showing.  Using my guessed definitions I have no problems, of course I'm assuming there's only one public static method and some basic definitions, etc.

Would be more helpful to see your actual code, though, for those classes or a skeleton.  Using these though, it works.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public enum EffectType
{
    A,
    B
}

public class Effect
{
    public EffectType Type { get; set; }
}

public class EffectResult
{
    public EffectType Type { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public EffectResult(EffectType type, bool success)
    {
        Type = type;
        Success = success;
    }
}

public class EffectMethods
{
    public static EffectResult Blend(Effect effect)
    {
        bool success = true;
        return new EffectResult(effect.Type, success);
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var methods = typeof (EffectMethods).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        var result = methods[0].Invoke(null, new object[] { new Effect { Type = EffectType.A } });

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```